# VB.NET UTF-8 to String

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting database from MySql in my VB.NET datgridview1.
By clicking any record number, details showed in richtextbox1.

My database is in UTF-8 Format, by clicking any record detail are come like this

```
&#1593;&#1605;&#1585;&#1575;&#1606; &#1582;&#1575;&#1606; &#1575;&#1608;&#1585; &#1575;&#1606;&#1608;&#1588;&#1705;&#1575; &#1588;&#1585;&#1605;&#1575; &#1705;&#1740; &#1606;&#1574;&#1740; &#1601;&#1604;&#1605; &#1705;&#1575; &#1662;&#1729;&#1604;&#1575; &#1657;&#1585;&#1740;&#1604;&#1585; &#1580;&#1575;&#1585;&#1740; 

&#1657;&#1585;&#1740;&#1604;&#1585; &#1580;&#1575;&#1585;&#1740;
```

I need to decode those values to show the right Character in my richtextbox1 
before showing any record, should be character not UTF-8 format.

This is URDU-ARABIC database, each record is different from other, so it should be render all record individual.

Comment: How are you getting the information from the database? Can you share the connection string (without the credentials, of course)? How are you displaying them?

Comment: Your database is **not** utf-8, whatever program wrote the string used HTML encoding.  Garbage in, garbage out, you ought to fix the database.  You can rescue it with HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(), it translates it to "عمران خان اور انوشکا شرما کی نئی فلم کا پہلا ٹریلر جاری ٹریلر جاری".  No idea if that's correct.

Comment: Here's [how you convert UTF-8 to String](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_320.asp), but it expects a byte array as input.